# Main DIV height doesn't resize with content

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with main div (DIV with red borders) - it doesn't resize with content. What I've already tried is this approah:

```
div{
min-height:1%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

but in this case it doesn't work. I've even used this on inner elements, not only on outer DIV.

This inner DIV adds several spans:

```
<div id="spanOfferHeaderData" style="display:block;min-height:1%;overflow:hidden;min-width:1%;">                
    <span><strong>PONUDBA ŠT.: 000017-2017</strong><span><br>
    <span>Datum: 05.09.2017<span><br>
    <span>Datum veljavnosti: 07.09.2017</span><br>
    <span>Kraj izdaje: Ljubljana</span><br/>
    <span>Dogodek: Test dogodek</span><br>
    <span>Lokacija: Celje - Maribor</span><br>
    <span>Opis: Opis opis opis opis<span><br>
    <span>drugi Opis: Opis opis opis opis<span><br>
</div>
```

Only two spans are visible, other spans are not visible (because main DIV doesn't resize with content). What else can I do to resize main DIV with content?

I've put whole example [here](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/QMRoPK?editors=1010)

Comment: By resize do you mean expand vertically? If so the example you provided is working for me.

Comment: I've wrote that height doesn't resize. Yes, vertically. Which browser are you using?

Comment: This is very hard to understand when you've used only inline styles -.-

Comment: I'm using Chrome...

Comment: It's not working for me. Tried in Chrome and IE (both latest).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zpvvXtO.png

Comment: you should drop position:absolute and use regular positionning via display, float ..

Comment: @Felipe - It's the same for as it is for me - main DIV does not expand to vertical content. Take a look at the content and you'll see what's missing.

Comment: @G-Cyr - do you have working example, perhaps?

Comment: What is your final goal ? HTML structure also matters. 1)A first hint: content should make sense at screen without any style. 2) hint ,draw borders, shadows or background to each of your elements to see where they stand. 3)here comes styling via display(table,flex,grid,inline-block, whatever ..) or float and eventually sizing 4) drop

Comment: This is strange... content resizes with absolutely positioned DIV: https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/oeROdv?editors=1000. It does not resize in my case.

Comment: Some reading for the HTML part http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/ Absolute positionning should be used for  good reason and **only** once you already master css enough to build a layout from elements standing in the flow. Your code will not resize and will not show the rest. absolute is of the flow and you used overflow:hidden on table parent.

Comment: @FrenkyB the reason that DIV resizes is because it's not got a parent with overflow hidden on it hiding the amount it has resized...

Comment: about HTML structure, the use of  adress and microformat can be bring some visibility to your site.  this can help you redo the structure in an efficient way : http://microformats.org/code/hcard/creator  and this will be usefull too to give meanings to your content (search engines understand this too ... :) ) From there the styling should be made short without positionning :p . It s obviously a 2 columns layout with some vertical-alignement

Answer (score 1):

One of the DIV's wrapping your spans has the following CSS properties:

```
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
```

Position absolute removes it from the document flow and top is pushing it down by 180 pixels. You then have:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

On one of the containers parents meaning all elements within the container that expand out of the container have the overflowing content hidden from view.

I've forked your CodePen and removed those properties to get the result I think you wanted: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvdRqB?editors=1010

I've removed the absolute positioning as you've said you want the container to resize based on content but it will not count absolutely positioned elements as content because as I said previously they're removed from the document flow.

I highly recommend not using inline styles, also you're using some sort of table structure which isn't even being filled it is all collapsed and a mess, be careful with your structure and do it simply.

Comment: Using top is also the problem. Outer element resizes, but only for the height of inner element, not also the top property of inner element: https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/OjYYNO. Outer DIV is resized, but because top property is not taken into account, inner DIV slips out of view.